# Custom tabbar button does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabbar

I have created a custom tabbar and added a custom image on the center position. However, whenever I click on that custom button, it does not take me to the selected item.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage* buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_floating.png"];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    CGFloat heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    if (heightDifference < 0)
        button.center = self.tabBar.center;
    else
    {
        CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
        center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
        button.center = center;
    }

    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(myAction)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:button];

}

-(void) myAction
{
   // the following line is getting called
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that `self.tabBarController` isn't `nil`?

Comment: it seems it is `nil`? How do I fix it then?

Comment: Is it an outlet? Connect it properly in Interface Builder.

Comment: it is not an outlet.

Comment: You need to assign a value to the property then. You have not provided any details so that is all I can say.

Comment: I have added  a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that 'self` is a tab bar controller. Change:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
```

to

```
self.selectedIndex = 2;
```